# php mail function is not working with to variable

Tags: email, header, sendmail

Any time i use a variable for $to, the message isn't sent, and when i use "" for the email directly, it is sent. Below is my code...

```
            $snd = "mail@mail.com";

         $to = $snd; // this is your Email address
         $from = $frome; // this is the sender's Email address
         $titl = $title;
         $subject = "Quotes From Eagle";
         $message = $titl . " " . $quote;
         $headers = "From:" . $from;
         mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

But when i use the below, it is sent.

```
         $to = "mail@mail.com"; // this is your Email address
         $from = $frome; // this is the sender's Email address
         $titl = $title;
         $subject = "Quotes From Eagle";
         $message = $titl . " " . $quote;
         $headers = "From:" . $from;
         mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

where am I getting this wrong?.
Thanks

Comment: You're missing a `;` at the end of the first line. Please don't tag your question with PHPMailer if you're not using PHPMailer, though judging by your question, you probably should be.

Comment: Yea thanks but same issue.

Comment: What is the return value from the call to `mail()`? What does your mail server’s log say? (You must have one to use `mail()`)